# Indexing sliced array in matlab???

Tags: arrays, matlab, list, slice

I know that there are some well-known issues with indexing arrays in matlab.  However, there is one in particular that I've never been able to understand:

This works just fine :

```
S =

     1     3     4     2
     4     5    24     1

v= S(1,:)

v =

     1     3     4     2

v(1)

ans =

     1
```

But this throws an error:

```
S(1,:)(1)
Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.
```

Why is this?  I still don't understand from a high level why this doesn't work.
I am a CS student, so, if I could have the principle and/or concept driving  this error, that'd be great.  Thanks!

Comment: You can simply use `S(1,1)`

Comment: It's an error purely because the MATLAB language does not currently implement index cascading nor indexing on literals, save for structs and objects using dynamic field access (mostly because it's compulsory for full functionality in my view).  It's just the language.

Comment: Okay, thanks to both of you.  no "indexing on literals"  makes sense.  thanks.